# background-color won't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website on which I'm currently working and it seems on Chrome that it won't display the `background-color` when you scroll down. It switches to it after a while, but only right at the top, and it seems it's not really the `background-color` taking effect, but instead it's the large background image that disappears and its background is white so it gives this impression.

Any idea on how I can fix this? The CSS is set to the appropriate `<div>` tags, it works on Firefox and other browsers, but it doesn't like Chrome for some reason.

Ideas?

So i'm talking about this problem. The background of the text should be white as you scroll up (i'm on Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)) :

Comment: Homepage, first large background image?

Comment: Please see the screenshot in the Edit

Comment: What's your method for hiding the big picture? can provide that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's a problem in Chrome(58.0) but it work in Firefox(53.0).

It's regarding CSS `z-index`.
The children of element: `.full_width_inner` need : `z-index` declaration.

```
.full_width_inner > * {
    z-index : 10;
}
```

Comment: I love you so much right now ! (sau pe romaneste, te iubesc, dude :))) )

Comment: Cu placere! Ma bucur ca te-a ajutat. 
Chiar a aparut cand ma uitam pe sectiunea CSS. :)))

Comment: asr eopir mpoer coer dkif mjds nfir nuw :)

Answer (score 1):

In chrome your div with class `carousel-inner` in style has only `display: block` or `display: none`. But in firefox same div in style has `transform: translateY(some number)`

Also in firefox this div has some other extra classes that are not in chrome. `skrollable-between` and `skrollable`